# How to print a dictionary sorted by values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I need to print a python dictionary that is sorted by values. To sort the dictionary I used this code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

The dictionary is well sorted, but the output is something like this:

```
[('Apple', '1'), ('Pears', '2'), ('Bananas', '3')]
```

I'd prefer:

```
Apple : 1
Pears : 2
Bananas : 3
```

I tried this wrong code:

```
dSorted = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
for i in dSorted:
    print(i + " : "+ dSorted[i])
```

How can I get this result? And, to understand better, when I use `(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))` the result is no longer a dictionary, but a different data structure, right?

Comment: What is in `dSorted`?

Comment: No he is asking how to format print results differently...

Comment: Sorry Scott, I edited the question. Paritosh I found the way to sort the dictionary looking that question, but not how to print it. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Correct, you get a list of tuples. more specifically, `d.items()` itself is a different type of view. you can turn the end result of the sort back into a dictionary by assinging or consuming it accordingly if you're on python 3.6+ After that you can just print as you like.

Comment: Try `sorted(d, key=lambda e: e[1])`

Comment: I'm using python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating a tuple of lists.  So just iterate the keys and values and print as you want

```
dSorted = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
for key,value in dSorted:
        print(key + " : "+ value)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using a recent version of python (in which dictionaries keep the order), if so, just make another dict out of the sorted list.

```
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
print(sorted_dict)
```